# Bootstrap 3.1.1 - Setting a link to a Modal on an other site?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How can I set a Link from mypage-x.html to a modal that exists on mypage-y.html?

Comment: use html a tag with href in that.
Check this
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do it would be with the use of parameters in the url. You will need to write a javasript function that looks for the parameter and then opens the modal if it is there. Here is an example. The link should be `<a href="mypage-y.html?m=myModal1>` The ?m is a parameter and the myModal1 is the value for that parameter. You could then write some jquery like this to check for the existence of the parameter and then open that modal. You would need to give the modal an id of myModal1 (or change the parameter in the url to whatever you want) `<div id="myModal1" class="modal ...`

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
        return null;
    }
    else{
        return results[1] || 0;
    }
}
$(function() {
    var m = $.urlParam('m');
    if (m != null)
    {
        $('#' + m).modal('show');
    }
});
```